# How to change namespace of import in all files in project in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I need to change the namespace in all files in my project. In instance, from "import com.company.myapi" to "import com.functions.exc.myapi"
I don't have library in which com.functions.exc.myapi is situated,since I need to change manually. How can I speed up the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select 'Edit' -> 'Find'->'Replace in Files' & then under first search box use "import com.company.myapi" & second search box would be "import com.functions.exc.myapi".

Use file mask as *.java & select `In Project` option for replacement.

Hope this works for you.